# Main and meta have too low contrast between text and the background

Tags: support, design

<sub>Not a duplicate of [question link visited/unvisited colors (new questions are "grayed out")](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/question-link-visited-unvisited-colors-new-questions-are-grayed-out)</sub>

I have tried (in vain, on other sites) to draw the devs' attention to low contrast of the 2015-vintage css. This post is a (probably futile) plea to reconsider and notch the contrast up. I guesstimate that the main page has become three to five per cent slower to read although have got no hard evidence to back that up.

[image: Contrast or lack thereof]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Contrast looks fine to me - not saying you're wrong, just curious what you're seeing.

Comment: @AviD - done....

Comment: @DeerHunter Contrast looks fine to me on that screenshot. Can you take a photograph of your screen? It may be your display configuration.

Comment: @Polynomial - not possible at the moment, am afraid. Have tried several displays, though - the discomfort is mostly psychological.

Comment: If multiple monitors have been tried, perhaps it's your video card, or your assigned colour profile (try Adobe sRGB). Failing that - perhaps you have problems with your vision? The latter would be a reason to perhaps darken the text, as we like to be inclusive regardless of physical ability.

Comment: @Polynomial - had a checkup in January, no specs, color vision unimpaired. Will monitor the problem further.

Comment: As someone who has a genetic vision problem that makes it difficult to process information in blue (yep, it's a thing), I agree that the contrast (and hue) could be changed to make it easier to read without a browser script to bump the CSS settings.